# Windows PC starts, but no display signal

Tags: display

When plugging in the power cable, computer turns on, fans go and lights flicker, but the monitor doesn't find any signal. When pressing the PC power button in the front, it doesn't do anything. I get no beep codes. Below are the things I've tried:

-Used different cables—VGA, DVI, HDMI, and swapping between GPU and motherboard ports. (Motherboard only has VGA)

-Used different monitors.

-Reseated all internal peripherals.

-Cleaned RAM sticks

-Removed all external peripherals.

-Removed all internal power cables except for the 24-pin.

-Removed GPU with VGA in motherboard port.

-Took out CMOS battery for 5 minutes with PC unplugged to reset BIOS.

-Tested PSU 24-pin with voltmeter (3.3v, 5.15v, 12v). Only reading I got that was 0v was the purple wire.

The speaker started doing a buzzing sound when turning on. This started occurring after I tested the power supply. Hopefully I didn't just mess something... lol

Answer (score 0):

> Tested PSU 24-pin with voltmeter (3.3v, 5.15v, 12v). Only reading I
> got that was 0v was the purple wire.

If you can only see zero volts on the power supply, start by substituting a known working power supply.